# Ligatures and highlighting using sourcecodepro and listings

Tags: listings, ligatures, sourcecodepro

I have a problem using the *sourcecodepro* and `listings`. I want to suppress ligatures *and* bold (Java) keywords. I already tried using the `literate`-option but it doesn't work as expected. That's my current code:

## Code:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage[default]{sourcecodepro}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{%
  language=Java,
  keywordstyle=\bfseries,
  literate={fl}{f{}l}{2},
  morekeywords={float}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
  float f;
  int i;
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

## Result:

[image: Result]

Comment: I get no ligatures by default. How are you compiling? And which texsystem do you use?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I get them by default with pdflatex on TL2017 (Linux). With LuaLaTeX I don't get them.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I am using TexLive 2016 (Linux Mint).

Comment: @TeXnician I don't get them (inside listings!), I would find it very odd if it happens there due to the way listings work.

Comment: I sent email to the author of the `sourcecodepro` package. On the other hand, I only get the ligature *outside* listings (using no `literate` option in `lstlisting`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `fi` and `fl` ligatures are only produced *outside* listings (which shouldn't happen anyway, but it's a different problem).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[default]{sourcecodepro}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{%
  language=Java,
  keywordstyle=\bfseries,
  morekeywords={float}
}

\begin{document}

\texttt{ff fi fl ffi ffl} % bad

\begin{lstlisting}
  float f;
  int i;
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You're right. That's curious, because some time ago, I had to add `literate={fl}{f{}l}{2}` to suppress ligatures *inside* listings. Seems that this is not necessary anymore.

Answer (score 8):

Using an additional group around the replacement solves the problem.

[image: source code]

Btw: [You should not use `minimal`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42114/124577).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[default]{sourcecodepro}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{%
  language=Java,
  keywordstyle=\bfseries,
  literate={fl}{{f{}l}}2,
  morekeywords={float}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
  float f;
  int i;
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

---

*Update:* Disabling ligatures via `microtype` allows also the use of the keyword.

[image: f ligatures]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[default]{sourcecodepro}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{microtype}
\DisableLigatures[f]{encoding = *, family = tt }

\lstset{%
  language=Java,
  keywordstyle=\bfseries,
  morekeywords={float}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
  float f;
  int i;
\end{lstlisting}

floating away

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! But I also want `float` to be typeset bold. How can I now achieve this? PS: Good to know about `minimal`! :-)

Comment: @dawu Added another approach.

Comment: Finally, it's time for me to deal with `microtype`.

Comment: One last question: Why looks the 'fl' outside of `lstlisting` so 'strange'? Is it a lack of ligatures in *sourcecodepro*? (I'm new to such font details.)

Comment: @dawu What do you mean with "so strange"? It's probably how the font designer wanted it to be. Not every font has a ligature that really connects both letters.